# How to position a TextBlock always at the bottom of the view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to put a **TextBlock** at the **bottom** of the view to inform users something. Each of the views height are different, user could use ScrollViewer to scroll the view.

 I want no matter how long the view is, the TextBlock always at the bottom of the view, **user need not to scroll the Scrollbar to the bottom of the view to see the message**. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two grids. one for your purpose where you add all your view and second for information text like below.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
<RowDefinition Height="30"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- This is your main grid in ScrollViewer-->
<ScrollViewer> 
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" >

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>

<!-- This is information Text which is always at bottom -->
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Text="Your Message" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Position the ScrollViewer around the first Grid can implement the effect what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about positioning,did you tried this,

```
<TextBlock ... HorizontalAlignment="Centre" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

if my understanding is wrong,please let me know.